# Phpmyadmin Error- A new statement was found but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near select)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have a trigger, here is the snippet:

```
BEGIN
    declare radius int;
    set @radius = (select radius from parameter);
    insert into activity(tweetid) VALUES (@radius); 
END
```

"Select" is being highlighted within phpmyadmin and the message says:

> A new statement was found but no delimiter between it and the previous
>   one. (near select).

I've tried everything to rectify the issue and I still can't get the trigger to work properly. No data is being inserted into the activity table. Please note that the parameter table only has one record and will remain that way. I also couldn't find anything on this site that would help with this.

Comment: Just `insert into activity(tweetid) SELECT radius from parameter;` is all that's needed here. [documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: +@JNevill That doesn't solve the issue at hand. The insert statement is there for debugging purposes. The original trigger is long and I spent hours trying to figure out what the issue was then it boiled down to the radius variable.

Comment: Perhaps you could use `SELECT INTO` instead: `SELECT radius INTO @radius FROM parameter;`.  Is that `SET` occuring inside a SELECT that isn't shown here?

Comment: @JNevill Thanks.

Comment: What is `parameter`?  `@radius` does not need to be declared.  Don't you need to say `NEW` or `OLD` somewhere?  Read examples of `TRIGGERs`.